# In Vuex, how do I access the root state from the state definition within a namespaced module?

Tags: vuex

I'm using Vuex 3.2.0 with modules.

In one of my modules I need access to the rootState from within the initial `state: { ... }` definition. How do I do this?

```
// my-module.js
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        // I can't actually use `rootState` here so how do I access it?
        foo: rootState.appConfig.bar + 'baz';
    },
    mutations: { ... },
    actions: { ... },
    getters: { ... }
}
```

I don't want to use a getter without any actual state value because I need to be able to mutate this value.

Comment: you can store the 'baz' part in my-modle.js, modify it at any time and use getter to combine a rootState prop with this one.

Comment: Yes, good point, and I did realize that after posting. Still, I'm curious if there is any way to do this, anyway. If this were a regular Vue component, and it was `data:` instead of `state:` then I could access `this.$root.appConfig.bar` inside `data: { ... }`

Comment: In case of components you should use props and not a direct access to a parent component's data

Comment: Also you can add a mutation where initialize state.foo = rootState.appConfig.bar + 'baz'.